# Do you Connect with my Groove?

Tags: sql, postgresql, groovy

I'm new at [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy), and this is my first time writing a database connection script. It may *seem* like example code, but it is more like *test* code. It works as posted, and I'm planning to use this as a model for a larger business application, so I want to make sure I do it right.

Are there any [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) features that it could benefit from? Did I miss any edge cases, or anything else I could improve?

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def dbUrl      = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/GroovyTest"
def dbUser     = "Phrancis"
def dbPassword = "test"
def dbDriver   = "org.postgresql.Driver"

def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)

println "Sql Instance: " + sql

sql.execute """SET SEARCH_PATH TO groovy_test;"""

sql.execute """
        START TRANSACTION;
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
        CREATE TABLE test (
            id SERIAL,
            string TEXT,
            number INTEGER,
            decimal NUMERIC,
            datetime TIMESTAMP
            );
        COMMIT;"""

def params1 = ['''');DROP TABLE test;--''', 42, 3.14159, 'NOW()']
def params2 = ['Hello, World!', 99999999, 0.1209823098234, '2015-06-25']

sql.execute """
        START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO test (string, number, decimal, datetime)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP));
        COMMIT;""", params1

sql.execute """
        START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO test (string, number, decimal, datetime)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP));
        COMMIT;""", params2

sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM test;") { row ->
    println """
The row Id is: ${row.id}
The string is: ${row.string}
The number is: ${row.number}
The decimal is: ${row.decimal}
The date-time is: ${row.datetime}"""
}
sql.close()
```

Here is the stdout after this runs:

> ```
> Sql Instance: groovy.sql.Sql@385c9627
>
> The row Id is: 1
> The string is: ');DROP TABLE test;--
> The number is: 42
> The decimal is: 3.14159
> The date-time is: 2015-06-25 19:49:25.603991
>
> The row Id is: 2
> The string is: Hello, World!
> The number is: 99999999
> The decimal is: 0.1209823098234
> The date-time is: 2015-06-25 00:00:00.0
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Comment: Like Simon said, one normally uses the `"` quote in groovy when using GStrings and you can actually use them by replacing the `"Sql Instance: " + sql` part with `"Sql Instance: $sql"`. It surely won't make a dramatic difference, and if it is even better or worse is more of a matter of taste, but since you are just starting with groovy you can treat it as a small excercise in GStrings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Defining database connection parameters

It is not recommended to hard-code your connection parameters within the script.

You could for example parse the database properties [from an external Json source](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html). There are other methods available in Groovy as well, such as reading properties from XML, or from a `database.properties` file, or from a `*.groovy` file, but I think Json might be the one you would feel most comfortable with.

```
def dbProperties = new JsonSlurper().parseFile(new File('db.json'))
```

Where `db.json` is something like this:

```
{
    "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/GroovyTest",
    "user": "Phrancis",
    "password": "test",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}
```

And then instantiating the `Sql` object:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbProperties.url, dbProperties.user, dbProperties.password, dbProperties.driver)
```

#### Strings

`"""` are used for multi-line strings, for single-line strings it is overkill.

```
sql.execute """SET SEARCH_PATH TO groovy_test;"""
```

Can become:

```
sql.execute "SET SEARCH_PATH TO groovy_test;"
```

Additionally, `"` is used for `GString`, that will work just fine here but is not required, a normal `String` would be enough. So we can use `'` insteand so that it becomes:

```
sql.execute 'SET SEARCH_PATH TO groovy_test;'
```

Here you have a multi-line `GString`, but as you're not using any `GString`-specific features (variable interpolation for example), you can replace the `"""` with `'''`

```
sql.execute """
        START TRANSACTION;

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
        (...)
```

#### Duplicated SQL query string

This code is essentially repeated twice:

```
sql.execute """
        START TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO test (string, number, decimal, datetime)

            VALUES (?, ?, ?, CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP));

        COMMIT;""", params1
```

The only difference is that the second time `params1` is exchanged for `params2`.

There are three ways to fix this:

1. Extract the query string to a variable
2. Extract a method, which takes the params as input and performs the query
3. Extract a <strike>method</strike> closure. (Very similar to extracting a method)

First approach would look like this:

```
def query = """
        START TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO test (string, number, decimal, datetime)

            VALUES (?, ?, ?, CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP));

        COMMIT;"""

sql.execute query, params1
sql.execute query, params2
```

Second approach:

```
void sqlInsert(List<Object> params) {
    sql.execute """
        START TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO test (string, number, decimal, datetime)

            VALUES (?, ?, ?, CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP));

        COMMIT;""", params
}

sqlInsert query, params1
sqlInsert query, params2
```

Note that `sqlInsert query, params1` is the same as `sqlInsert(query, params1)`

Third approach:

```
def sqlInsert = { List<Object> params ->
    sql.execute """
        START TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO test (string, number, decimal, datetime)

            VALUES (?, ?, ?, CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP));

        COMMIT;""", params
}

sqlInsert.call(params1)
sqlInsert.call(params2)

// or alternatively
sqlInsert(params1)
sqlInsert(params2)
```